# How to access assets from resources sub folder in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

This is the javascript source in blade file.

```
<script src="{{ URL::to('resources/views/template/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js') }}"></script>
```

OR

```
<script src="{{ asset('resources/views/template/validate/jquery.bvalidator.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Both asset and URL::to doesn't work.
The actual file path is:
resources -> views -> template -> js

error shows 404 not found on local xampp server. its working fine in production. project is copy of production code.

I would appreciate for your kind support. thanks

Comment: You should move your file to `/public/` directory. so your asset/url will work if your file located on `public -> resources -> views -> template -> js` **Note :** `/resources/views/` is your blade file directory, not for your static files directory. Move your all static files on `/public/` folder

Comment: The above is the correct way to do it, you should put in your public folder, but if for some reason you don't want to `{{ resource_path('views/template/validate/jquery.bvalidator.min.js') }}`

Comment: i have treied , adding into public folder like https://localhost.com//public/js/app.js
But still cant access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static assets are usually stored in the `public` folder in Laravel. It would be wise to store all your JavaScript files in a separate folder inside the public folder, e.g. `public/js/`.

You could then access your files with the `asset()` function call, for example:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.bvalidator.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: yes, i have moved all assets in public , now its working. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to store files is in Public folder of Project.
Place your files within a folder in Public folder.

Like public/assets/folder

You can access it by following.

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/folder/jquery.js') }}"></script>
```

asset() helper by defualt hit in public folder of Project.